# Why can't I access a JLabel outside of the constructor?

Tags: java, jlabel

So I created a JLabel in the constructor of my main class, then, I have a separate method in the class to update it (updateLabel()). But can't access the Label from in the update method. How can I access it from inside the method? Thanks

```
public Difficulty(){
    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel((comboBox_9.getSelectedItem().toString()));
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(300, 70, 46, 23);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);
}

public void updateLabel(Skill skill){

}
```

In the update Label method I want to say `lblNewLabel.setText(skill.toString())`

But I can't access the label.

Comment: I guess because of the scope of the JLabel variable. The JLabel defined and created within the constructor will not be accessible out side of constructor.

Comment: Do you have something like `public class Foo { private JLabel label; public Foo() { label = new JLabel("Label"); } ... }`? Therefore: show us your code.

Comment: Could you please show us the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to consider variable scope: [Java Tutorials - Declaring Member Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html)

If you declare an object within the *scope* of your constructor then it won't be accessible elsewhere, for example your updateLabel() method.

Try declaring your JLabel as field, for instance:

```
private JLabel label;

public JLabelContainer() {
   label = new JLabel();
}

public void updateLabel(String text){
  label.setText(text);
}
```

Here, the label is declared at the field level, instantiated in the constructor and then accessed in the `updateLabel(..)` method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare it outside of the constructor to make it visible to other methods.If you declare it inside the constructor the it has a local scope not global which means it can be accessed only inside the constructor.In general everything declared inside a method can only be accessed inside that method

```
For example:
public class Foo{

   JLabel label=new JLabel("Global");//this has a global scope
   public Foo(){

      JLabel label_1=new JLabel("local scope");//this can't be accesed outside    //the constructor
    label_1.setText("new text");//but inside the constructor you can do what you want
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To access a variable in any method, it should be in the scope of that block. In case you want to access a variable anywhere in the class, then the variable should have a `public` access or at the minimum be a `private` instance variable.

In your case, since the `JLabel` has a `local` access in the constructor, the scope of that variable ends as soon as the constructor ends.

For your case, this could be one of the viable solutions:

```
private JLabel lblNewLabel;

public Difficulty(){
    lblNewLabel = new JLabel((comboBox_9.getSelectedItem().toString()));
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(300, 70, 46, 23);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);
}

public void updateLabel(Skill skill){
    //access lblNewLabel here.
}
```